# Replacing four lines with sed

Tags: sed

I have the following code in a larger file

```
   }
   catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
   }
```

I am trying to delete these four lines out of the file using sed but cannot seem to figure it out. Each line may have preceding or trailing white space.

The following which I thought should work does not work:

```
sed '1N;$!N;s/.*}.*\n.*catch.*\n.*Error.*\n.*}.*//;P;D' myfile.php
```

The weird thing is that

```
sed '1N;$!N;s/.*}.*\n.*catch.*\n.*Error.*//;P;D' myfile.php
```

deletes the first three lines. And

```
sed '1N;$!N;s/.*catch.*\n.*Error.*\n.*}.*//;P;D' myfile.php
```

deletes the last three lines.

Why doesn't it work for all four lines?

I also don't completely understand why I need the $!N for this to work, so if you can explain what exactly that is doing that will help my understanding as well.

Thanks!

Comment: `sed` is best for line matching. For multi-line, you better use Perl. Also, see [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26284/40596)

Comment: You'll get a PHP syntax error if you keep the try block but remove the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/3;Ta;/^\s*}\n.*catch.*\n.*Error.*\n\s*}$/d;P;D' file
```

This solution make a moving window of four lines in the pattern space (PS) and if the desired pattern matches the PS those four lines are deleted. Otherwise the first of the lines is printed and then deleted and another line appended to the PS and the match tried again until a match or the end of the file is reached.

N.B. sed by design removes any newlines before populating the PS. the `N` command appends a newline followed by the next line to the PS.If the `N` command is called following the end of the file, no further commands are executed and the PS is printed (unless the `-n` option is in operation).

Comment: That works great! Thanks. Just trying to understand it now. :)

Comment: I think I understand everything except for the `/&/3;Ta` part. Can you explain what is going on there?

Comment: @kojow7 substitution using the `s/.../.../` command can be used to replace a  specific occurence of the matching (lefthandside or lhs) pattern. In this case the lhs is a newline and the replacement is itself. This provides a mechanism to count the number of newlines. The `T` command can be used to branch to a place holder ( in this case `a`) if the substitution was unsuccessful (the dual to this is the `t` command for a successful substitution).   So in essence, the sed script keeps looping until the pattern space contains 3 newlines (4 lines). if the `:a;N;s/\n/&/3;Ta` is used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444224/replacing-four-lines-with-sed/32444504#comment52752108_32444224), you'll get a syntax error in PHP if you remove the catch block.

Btw, you can use `php` for that task. PHP supports recursive regex patterns which can be used here:

```php
<?php

$string = <<<'EOF'
   }   
   catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Error: '. $e->getMessage();
   }   
EOF;

// Check http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.recursive.php
$pattern = '/catch .*\{(((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*)\}/';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

`sed` does not pattern recursion in that way.

Comment: I am aware that I cannot use a try block without a catch block. I have been able to remove the try just fine, it is the catch block that I was not able to remove. I have hundreds of files I am wanting to remove the try/catch block from so using php will be more complicated than just using a simple sed command.

Comment: The big advantage of the above code is that it matches blocks between `{ }` recursively. Meaning any if, switch or whatever block in the catch block. Iterating trough a bunch of files is easily possible using PHP. Should I show that?

Comment: You are welcome to show it, however, it is unrelated to my question. I was interested in learning how to do this in sed which potong answered already. If I was open to doing it any way I would not have specifically mentioned sed. Also, if you look at the code I posted I have no need for recursion. It may, however, help with a future task I need to do so I will definitely keep it in mind.

Comment: Don't you see that the `sed` command by potong is super weak? It will break if the catch  block contains an `if` block. `sed` has no support for recursive regexes, I told that. If you want to learn `sed`, you picked the wrong example. Believe me.

Comment: Btw, If you want a plain stupid sed for that purpose, meaning searching for `catch (PDOException)` and delete the subsequent 3 lines, then use `sed '/catch (PDOException/{N;N;d}'`

Comment: That's almost what I need, but I need the } on the line before the catch as well.

Comment: In that case I would use `sed '/}/{N;/catch (PDOException/{;N;N;d}}'`